# Android Implement AsymmetricGridView

Tags: java, android, xml, view, grid

Hello i have some problem with implementation of AssymetricGridView it still crashing but i dont know what is wrong how to implement it correctly with my adapter there is error Link to AssymetricGridView library. Thank you

```
Adapter must be an instance of AsymmetricGridViewAdapter
                                                                      at com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AsymmetricGridView.setAdapter(AsymmetricGridView.java:71)
                                                                      at com.gabriel.movies.fragment.MainFragment.render(MainFragment.java:140)
                                                                      at com.gabriel.movies.fragment.MainFragment$MyTask.onPostExecute(MainFragment.java:228)
                                                                      at com.gabriel.movies.fragment.MainFragment$MyTask.onPostExecute(MainFragment.java:161)
```

My code

```
<com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AsymmetricGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

AsymmetricGridView gridview;
List<ItemCategory> list;
AdapterCategory adapter;

    gridview = (AsymmetricGridView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setRequestedColumnWidth(Utils.dpToPx(getActivity(), 120));

    list = new ArrayList<ItemCategory>();

    adapter = new AdapterCategory(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_worcipe_main_item, list);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and adapter code

```
public class AdapterCategory extends ArrayAdapter<ItemCategory> {
    ItemCategory object;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<ItemCategory> item;
    private int row;



     public AdapterCategory(Activity act, int resource, List<ItemCategory> arrayList) {
            super(act, resource, arrayList);
            this.activity = act;
            this.row = resource;
            this.item = arrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            if ((item == null) || ((position + 1) > item.size()))
                return view;

            object = item.get(position);

            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_image);

            holder.title.setText(object.getCategoryName());

            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(RecipeConfig.SERVER_URL + "/upload/" +
                    object.getCategoryImageurl()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail).into(holder.image);

            return view;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            public TextView title;
            public ImageView image;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, you need a class, that extends form AsymmetricItem. This should look like this:

```
public class DemoItem implements AsymmetricItem {
private int columnSpan;
private int rowSpan;
private int position;
private String text;
public DemoItem() {
    this(1, 1, 0,"");
}

public DemoItem(int columnSpan, int rowSpan, int position,String text) {
    this.columnSpan = columnSpan;
    this.rowSpan = rowSpan;
    this.position = position;
    this.text=text;
}

public DemoItem(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@Override public int getColumnSpan() {
    return columnSpan;
}

@Override public int getRowSpan() {
    return rowSpan;
}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

@Override public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s: %sx%s", position, rowSpan, columnSpan);
}

@Override public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    columnSpan = in.readInt();
    rowSpan = in.readInt();
    position = in.readInt();
}

@Override public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(columnSpan);
    dest.writeInt(rowSpan);
    dest.writeInt(position);
}

/* Parcelable interface implementation */
public static final Parcelable.Creator<DemoItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DemoItem>() {

    @Override public DemoItem createFromParcel(@NonNull Parcel in) {
        return new DemoItem(in);
    }

    @Override @NonNull
    public DemoItem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DemoItem[size];
    }
};
}
```

Then you need to create your Adapter, which should look like this(exept you should recycle the views):

```
public class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DemoItem> {

private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public GridAdapter(Context context, List<DemoItem> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public GridAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0);
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    DemoItem item = getItem(position);
    View    v = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.adapter_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(item.getText());
    return v;
}

@Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

public void appendItems(List<DemoItem> newItems) {
    addAll(newItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setItems(List<DemoItem> moreItems) {
    clear();
    appendItems(moreItems);
}
}
```

And finally, when you have all of that, you can implement everything in your Activity/Fragment like this:

```
 private ListAdapter adapter;
    private AsymmetricGridView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_gridview, container, false);
        listView = (AsymmetricGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAllowReordering(true);
        final List<DemoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        items.add(new DemoItem(2,2,0,"Example Text 1"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(1,1,0,"Example Text 2"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(1,1,0,"Example Text 3"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(2,2,0,"Example Text 4"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(1,1,0,"Example Text 5"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(1,1,0,"Example Text 6"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(1,1,0,"Example Text 7"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(2,2,0,"Example Text 8"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(1,1,0,"Example Text 9"));
        items.add(new DemoItem(1,1,0,"Example Text 10"));

        adapter = new GridAdapter(getContext(), items);
        listView.setAdapter(new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter(getContext(), listView, adapter));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And that's it, i hope i could help you.